# Isotropic Radiation

Tags: radiation

I am measuring exposure from a near-isotropic brachytherapy source in air using an ion chamber just from one side. I'm just wondering if I need to consider the back side. Is there some sort of correction factor to get the complete exposure rate of the source?

Answer (score 2):

If your source is isotropic, then your correction factor is just the total solid angle you're measuring as a fraction of $4\pi$ (to go from total exposure to measured exposure). For measuring one hemisphere, multiply your results by 2 to get the total exposure.

If your source is anisotropic, with a radiant intensity of $F(\theta,\phi)$ watts/steradian, and you're measuring over a particular angular region $D$, then the correction factor is

$$\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi F (\theta,\phi) \sin (\theta)d\theta d\phi}{\int\int_D F (\theta,\phi) \sin (\theta) d\theta d\phi} $$

The numerator is just the total luminosity of the source.

Comment: if the source is anisotropic I-125, will the will the factor be. 2 x F(r,theta) anisotropic factor(r,theta)

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that, as shown above. But this kind of correction factor is only useful if you already know $F$, so now I'm confused as to what exactly you want to do.